# Why is Cinnamon blocking function keys? F1-12 aren't getting to the terminal

Tags: command-line, vim, cinnamon, function-keys

I map the function keys in vim to modify a ton of stuff, from syntax line numbering to autoindenting to changing the tab width and syntax highlighting.

Unity was a major problem here because if I mapped F7 (and a few others, I don't remember which) in vim, using them would freeze the terminal until I dropped to the hardware console and did a kill -9 on vim.

So I switched to Cinnamon, which has been a huge improvement in many ways, but I've entirely lost the function keys.  None of them are shortcut mapped, so I know it's not that.  What else could be causing the problem and how do I fix it?